# Read from multiple files for longer duration in Python

Tags: python, file, duration

Below code will read from multiple files and print, and after printing it stops execution. However multiple processes will be adding data to these files at an interval.

How to keep monitoring these files and read for longer duration ?

```
import glob
list_of_files=glob.glob('./*.txt')

for filename in list_of_files:
    f=open(filename, "r")
    data_list=f.readlines()
    print(data_list)
```

Comment: what do you mean by for longer duration? Just do whatever you want with the contents of the files in that `for-loop`

Comment: if i open in write mode, other processes might not be able to write. Any other alternative?

Comment: yes. it is similar, only difference is that was for one file. i need similar solution for multiple files